# django cannot find image

Tags: python, django

I have a site with the following file structure:

```
MyProject
 +--- media
       +--- user_1
             +--- my_image
 +--- profiles
       +--- templates
             +--- profiles
                   +--- create.html
                   +--- login.html
                   +--- profile.html
       +--- urls.py
       +--- models.py
       +--- views.py
 +--- MyProject
       +--- settings.py
```

In `settings.py` I have my `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` and `MEDIA_URL = '/'` set like so and I have `'django.template.context_processors.media'` added to `context_processors`. In my `urls.py` I have the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile/(?P<profile_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.Details, name = "account"),
    url(r'^update/', views.Update_Profile, name = "update"),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT) +\
    static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The template `profile.html` looks like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load profiles_extras %}

{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">

      <!-- Store Information -->
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Store Information</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="center-block">

            <!-- Change picture form -->
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'update' %}" class="hidden form-inline" id="picture-change-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="picture" accept="image/*">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>

            {% if profile.logo %}
              <img src="{{ profile.logo.url }}" class="img-responsive" id="logo" alt="Store Logo">
            {% else %}
              <img src="{% static 'no-image.png' %}" class="img-responsive" id="logo" alt="Store Logo">
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When a profile image is uploaded, this function in `profiles.views.py` is called.

```
@login_required
def Update_Profile(request):
    update_profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
    has_updated = False
    if ('picture' in request.FILES):
        update_profile.update_logo( request.FILES['picture'] )
    return redirect('profiles.views.Details', profile_id = update_profile.id)
```

This function in turn calls `update_logo` in `profiles.models.py`:

```
def update_logo(self, value):
    self.logo = value
    self.save()
```

However, when I upload a photo, `my_image.png` it comes up as `user_1/my_image.png` and the server returns a 404 because the file wasn't found. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django have defined urls for `/profile/`, `/update/`, `/static/` and `/`.

Url `/user_1/` is not defined.

Try to change `MEDIA_URL` to `/media/`.

Comment: I attempted that as well but alas it did not work. How would I define `/user_1/`?

Comment: If You change `MEDIA_URL` to `/media/`, then uploaded images will be available at `/media/user_1/` and You don't need to define `/user_1/` url.

Comment: Try to remove all data from `Profile` model

Comment: But this image is specific to user 1 so it seems appropriate for user 1 to have his own directory.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Uploaded images for user 1 will be available at `/media/user_1/`.

Comment: I tried to remove all the data from the `Profile` model and re-enter but that hasn't fixed the problem. I'm really at a loss here.